# App Layout of angular components throws error with .scss

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-pub, dart-webui

I am trying to apply **App Layout** component of material design angular_components in AngularDart with the following codes, but the system throws an error while applying it through **.scss**.
Kindly help me to know what's missing in the following to make the app run accordingly.

error:

```
C:\Users\Tushar Rai\Desktop\Project files\Angular_Dart_Base_App\angular_dart_base_app>pub serve
Loading source assets...
Loading sass_builder, angular, test/pub_serve and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers...
Serving angular_dart_base_app web  on http://localhost:8080
Serving angular_dart_base_app test on http://localhost:8081
Build completed successfully
[web]  GET Served 3 cached assets.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS on angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart]:
web\packages\angular_dart_base_app\src\components\app_layout\app_layout_component.template.dart:29:1:
Can't read 'package:angular_dart_base_app/src/components/app_layout/app_layout_component.scss.shim.dart' (Could not find asset angular_dart_base_app|lib/src/components/app_layout/app
_layout_component.scss.shim.dart.).
import 'package:angular_dart_base_app/src/components/app_layout/app_layout_component.scss.shim.dart' as import0;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS on angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart]:
web\packages\angular_dart_base_app\src\components\app_layout\app_layout_component.template.dart:62:56:
Not a compile-time constant.
const List<dynamic> styles$AppLayoutComponent = const [import0.styles, import1.styles];
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS on angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart]:
web\packages\angular_dart_base_app\src\components\app_layout\app_layout_component.template.dart:62:56:
Not a compile-time constant.
const List<dynamic> styles$AppLayoutComponent = const [import0.styles, import1.styles];
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Dart2JS on angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart]:
1 warning(s) and 3 hint(s) suppressed in package:angular_components.
[Warning from Dart2JS on angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart]:
2 hint(s) suppressed in package:angular.
[Dart2JS on angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart]:
1 warning(s) suppressed in package:angular_dart_base_app.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:09.925765 to compile angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart.
Build completed with 3 errors.
[web]  GET main.dart.js => Could not find asset angular_dart_base_app|web/main.dart.js.
```

app_layout_component.html

```
<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer" [attr.end]="end ? '' : null">
    <material-list *deferredContent>
        <div group class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
        <div group>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Star
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
        <div group>
            <div label>Tags</div>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Favorites
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
    </material-list>
</material-drawer>
<material-content>
    <header class="material-header shadow">
        <div class="material-header-row">
            <material-button icon
                             class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
                <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <span class="material-header-title">Simple Layout</span>
            <div class="material-spacer"></div>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
                <a href="#AppLayout">Link 1</a>
            </nav>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
                <a href="#AppLayout">Link 2</a>
            </nav>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
                <a href="#AppLayout">Link 3</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
        et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
        veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
        legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <h3>Options</h3>
        <material-toggle [(checked)]="end" label="end">
        </material-toggle>
    </div>
</material-content>
```

app_layout_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/material_persistent_drawer.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/content/deferred_content.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_button/material_button.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_icon/material_icon.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list_item.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_toggle/material_toggle.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'app-layout',
    directives: const [
      DeferredContentDirective,
      MaterialButtonComponent,
      MaterialIconComponent,
      MaterialListComponent,
      MaterialListItemComponent,
      MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective,
      MaterialToggleComponent,
    ],
    templateUrl: 'app_layout_component.html',
    styleUrls: const [
      'app_layout_component.scss',
      'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
    ])
class AppLayoutComponent {
  bool end = false;
}
```

app_layout_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';

:host {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}

.controls {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
  color: $mat-white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

import 'package:angular_dart_base_app/src/components/app_layout/app_layout_component.dart';
import 'src/components/todo_list/todo_list_component.dart';

// AngularDart info: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular
// Components info: https://webdev.dartlang.org/components

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [
    materialDirectives,
    AppLayoutComponent,
    TodoListComponent],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent {
  // Nothing here yet. All logic is in TodoListComponent.
}
```

app_component.html

```
<h1>My First AngularDart App</h1>
<app-layout></app-layout>
<todo-list></todo-list>
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: angular_dart_base_app
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
version: 0.0.1
#homepage: https://www.example.com
#author: Tushar Rai <email@example.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0
  angular_components: ^0.8.0
  sass_builder: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^1.0.0
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  test: ^0.12.0

transformers:
- sass_builder
- angular:
    entry_points:
      - web/main.dart
      - test/**_test.dart
- test/pub_serve:
    $include: test/**_test.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter

# Uncomment the following in sdk 1.24+ to make pub serve
# use dartdevc (webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc).
#web:
#  compiler:
#    debug: dartdevc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `'app_layout_component.scss'` to `'app_layout_component.css'` in app_layout_component.dart file

app_layout_component.dart

```
@component(
styleUrls: const [
      'app_layout_component.css',
      'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
    ])
```